# Could not find model PipelineModel

Tags: amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

When I try to build models to create a pipeline as follows,

```
    <code for the preprocessor>
    preprocessor = sklearn_preprocessor.create_model() #successful

    <code for the estimator>
    xgb_model_step = xgb_model.create_model() #successful    
    
    sm_model = PipelineModel(name='model', role=role, models=[preprocessor, xgb_model_step]) #successful
    sm_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', endpoint_name=end) <--- failure!
```

The models are created successfully. In the deploy line I get an error as,

`ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Could not find model data at s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-1356784978535/sagemaker-scikit-learn-2021-06-04-20-07-55-519/output/model.tar.gz.`

I am not sure how I can specify the path and make the deploy successful. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Can you add the complete code, so that it is reproducible? It is hard for us to develop a solution if we can't see the error.